# UITableView Async image not always correct

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, mkmapsnapshotter

I have a `UITableView` and during the initial loading of my app it sends multiple API requests. As each API request returns, I add a new row to the `UITableView`. So the initial loading adds rows in random orders at random times (Mostly it all happens within a second).

During cell setup, I call an Async method to generate an `MKMapKit` `MKMapSnapshotter` image.

I've used async image loading before without issue, but very rarely I end up with the image in the wrong cell and I can't figure out why.

I've tried switching to `DiffableDataSource` but the problem remains.

In my `DiffableDataSource` I pass a closure to the cell that is called when the image async returns, to fetch the current cell in case it's changed:

```
let dataSource = DiffableDataSource(tableView: tableView) {
            (tableView, indexPath, journey) -> UITableViewCell? in
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "busCell", for: indexPath) as! JourneyTableViewCell
            cell.setupCell(for: journey) { [weak self] () -> (cell: JourneyTableViewCell?, journey: Journey?) in
                
                if let self = self
                {
                    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? JourneyTableViewCell
                    let journey = self.sortedJourneys()[safe: indexPath.section]
                    return (cell, journey)
                }
                return(nil, nil)
            }
            
            return cell
        }
```

Here's my cell setup code:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    
    setMapImage(nil)
    journey = nil
    asyncCellBlock = nil
}

func setupCell(for journey:Journey, asyncUpdateOriginalCell:@escaping JourneyOriginalCellBlock) {
    
    self.journey = journey
    
    // Store the async block for later
    asyncCellBlock = asyncUpdateOriginalCell
    
    // Map
    if let location = journey.location,
       (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(location.coordinate2D))
    {
        // Use the temp cached image for now while we get a new image
        if let cachedImage = journey.cachedMap.image
        {
            setMapImage(cachedImage)
        }
        
        // Request an updated map image
        journey.createMapImage {
            [weak self] (image) in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                if let asyncCellBlock = self?.asyncCellBlock
                {
                    let asyncResult = asyncCellBlock()
                    if let cell = asyncResult.cell,
                       let journey = asyncResult.journey
                    {
                        if (cell == self && journey.id == self?.journey?.id)
                        {
                            self?.setMapImage(image)
                            
                            // Force the cell to redraw itself.
                            self?.setNeedsLayout()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        setMapImage(nil)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is just a race condition with the `UITableView` updating several times in a small period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because when the image is available then that index is not there. Since the table view cells are reusable, it loads the previous image since the current image is not loaded yet.

```
if let cachedImage = journey.cachedMap.image
    {
        setMapImage(cachedImage)
    }
else {
        // make imageView.image = nil
}
```

Comment: I've added my `prepareForReuse()` code above. I set the image to nil. It's almost as if every now and then it gets the wrong indexPath from the closure.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you already cache the image but I think you should prepare the cell for reuse like this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    let image = UIImage()
    self.yourImageView.image = image
    self.yourImageView.backgroundColor = .black
}
```

Comment: I've added my `prepareForReuse()` code above. I set the image to nil so it shouldn't carry over any previous image. I think the issue is coming from being handed the wrong indexPath/Object

Comment: I would still try to use prepareForReuse() to do that? Have you actually tried if it works?

Comment: I had the same problem in the past and it's not about having the wrong index but it is about scrolling to fast for the cell to be prepared for reuse and it shows the image used before.

Comment: I am not really sure that setting your image to nil will prepare the cell as you expect.  I think you gave to set an image rather the using nil. Can you check if the above code solve the problem?

Comment: I’ll add it and see how it goes. Thanks. It only happens on the odd occasion so I might not notice it for a while.